# BigQuery - Max datasets size

Tags: google-bigquery

Has the BigQuery's datasets a maximum size (GB of inserted data)?

I don't find an answer for this in BigQuery documentation. The quota policy page talks about the maximum size of uploaded files and the max number of load jobs per day but not specify a maximum size per dataset or table.

I need know how much data I can upload to a datasets for an academic research.

Thanks

Comment: How big is your project? Just wondering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unlimited" is a big word, but one of the strong points about BigQuery is you shouldn't be able to find the limit.

The daily limit is almost 10 petabytes per project per day. If you have more data than that, just keep pushing the next day, it should not break.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#import

(Before doing a multi-terabyte import, it's a good idea to contact sales, to make sure there is physical capacity ready to handle the theoretical limits)

Comment: Thanks, I had calculated a similar data size per day but I was not sure about a limit size over datasets in a large period of time.

Comment: If your data is in the terabytes range, you will have no problem. If your data is larger than that, BigQuery can handle it, but you should probably contact sales to talk about your capacity needs.

Comment: Added "(Before doing a multi-terabyte import, it's a good idea to contact sales, to make sure there is physical capacity ready to handle the theoretical limits)"

Comment: How many petabytes will fit in a single table? (We talk about BigQuery in a lecture and it would be great to have an answer for the audience)